# Axios not cancelling multiple requests

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to cancel all the previous requests when searching pokemons in input section.
I am able to search pokemon but everytime I search, my code renders one extra time. if I search bulbasor it shows multiple bulbasor

Initially it render 1 time.
after 1st search it renders 2 times.
after 2nd search it reander 3 times and so on...

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import Pokemon from './pokemon';
import { FaSearch } from 'react-icons/fa'

function App() {
  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([])
  const [pokeInput, setPokeInput] = useState('')
  const cancelToken = axios.CancelToken
  const source = cancelToken.source()

  useEffect(() => {
    for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`, {
        cancelToken: source.token
      })
        .then(res => {
          setPokemons((poke) => {
            return [...poke, res.data]
          })
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    }
    return () => source.cancel()
  }, [pokeInput])

  const pokeSort = pokemons.filter((pokemon) => {
    return pokemon.name.toLowerCase().includes(pokeInput.toLowerCase())
  })

  let pokeInputChange = (e) => {
    setPokeInput(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form className='search'>
        <h1>Search Pokemon</h1>
        <div className='form'>
          <input
            onChange={pokeInputChange}
            type="text"
            placeholder='Search Pokemon'
            id="pokeSearchBar"
            className='searchbar'
          />
          <span className='search_icon'><FaSearch /></span>
          <div className="extra1"></div>
          <div className="extra2"></div>
          <button className='go'>GO</button>
        </div>
      </form>

      {
        pokeSort.map((pokemon, index) => {
          console.log(pokemons)
          return (
            <Pokemon
              key={index}
              name={pokemon.name}
              type={pokemon.types}
              moves={pokemon.moves}
              height={pokemon.height}
              weight={pokemon.weight}
              front_image={pokemon.sprites.front_default}
              back_image={pokemon.sprites.back_default}
            />
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please post more code, especially anything where you are changing state which can cause a rerender

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you meant by render and what you're trying to do with `cancel`.  The way it's written you accumulate all the new API calls and they never get cleared.  Your `useEffect` isn't actually dependent on `pokeInput`.  If you remove that and change the line to `}, [])`  is that the behavior you're expecting?

Comment: @possum there is one more thing, my pokeSort.map function is rendering n time for nth element. Can I solve it?